# How to remove consumed messages from activemq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

[image]I need to remove message from activemq soon after I consumed it. For an example, I send a message to the queue, then I consume it and I need to remove it from queue. I have used a messagestorage here and a clear() method. Messages get added to the queue and delete only from message storage but not from queue. I need a way to remove messages from queue. Appreciate your help.!

I have tried below code.

#### Producer

```
@Component
public class JmsProducer {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Value("${gkz.activemq.queue}")
    String queue;
    
    public void send(Customer customer){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, customer);
    }
}
```

#### Consumer

```
@Component
public class JmsConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private MessageStorage customerStorage;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${gkz.activemq.queue}",containerFactory="jsaFactory")
    public void receive(Customer customer){
        System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + customer);
        customerStorage.add(customer);
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/api/customer")
public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    jmsProducer.send(customer);
    return customer;
}

@GetMapping(value="/api/customers")
public List<Customer> getAll(){
    List<Customer> customers = customerStorage.getAll();
    return customers;
}

@DeleteMapping(value="/api/customers/clear")
public String clearCustomerStorage() {
    customerStorage.clear();
    return "Clear All CustomerStorage!";
}
```

#### MessageStorage

```
public class MessageStorage {
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Customer customer) {
        customers.add(customer);
    }

    public void clear() {
        customers.clear();
    }

    public List<Customer> getAll(){
        return customers;
    }
}
```

#### ConnectionFactoryConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectionFactoryConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${gkz.activemq.broker.url}")
    String brokerUrl;
    
    @Value("${gkz.activemq.borker.username}")
    String userName;
    
    @Value("${gkz.activemq.borker.password}")
    String password;
    
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
    
    
    //Used for Receiving Message
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
 
    
    //Used for Sending Messages.
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
    
}
```

This whole code is available in https://grokonez.com/java-integration/distributed-system/activemq-producer-consumer-springboot-restapis-example

Comment: It's the purpose of a queue. Do you actually see that your messages are not removed after consumption ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel yes they are still in the queue. Please see the above screenshot attached

Comment: How about your `jsaFactory` defined in `@JmsListener` ? What kinda configurations did you override there? Can you add that in your question?

Comment: @buræquete I added the configurations. This whole code can be found in https://grokonez.com/java-integration/distributed-system/activemq-producer-consumer-springboot-restapis-example. Thanks

Comment: Can you just use without any custom `containerFactory` ? Also do you have `@EnableJms` annotation? Are you sure that you are consuming messages? Do you see those `System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + customer);` ?

Comment: @buræquete Yes I'm consuming messages. Please find the image I attached

Comment: I don't understand your problem, your messages are correctly dequeued. Are your consumers continually consuming ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Actually what I need to do is remove all the messages from queue. After message is dequeued, that message ned to be removed from queue. That's what I need to implement.

Comment: Do you persist your messages ? By default, I think that messages are directly removed when consumed. There is simply a `dequeued` counter for the metrics

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel When I add lots of messages to the queue, it is getting bigger. So I need to add msg to the queue, consume it and simply remove it from the queue. That is what my instructor asked me to do. [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e3mP_J1vRk5k9hheJexrRFEvBb2iRQRf)

Comment: What you show are just metrics ! It serves to monitor the queue and see if the messages are correctly consumed. Messages are removed once consumed in a queue, that's the point of a queue, you don't need to to anything.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I thought that much of messages are stored in the queue and if I add more, the queue will get bigger. So the messages are automatically getting removed from the queue when I consume them? So no need to purge? Thanks a lot for your comments.!

Comment: Since there is one and only one consumer for each message, there's no point to keep the message after consumption by default. If you really want to be sure of it, you can still test your system and continuously produce / consume messages, to see if you reach the memory / disk limit. But I doubt it

Comment: I searched for this issue and found this as a solution. But this doesn't work. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FmmPWW3Hi-L0oQPtD46bx0pIE9MMSaL7)

Answer (score 1):

Click the purge option on MQ later restart the MQ service. That will clear all the messages which are not in pending status.